Do LDS teach that God has a soul?
The question is: According to the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, does God have a soul?
Understandably, the answer will have to incorporate the LDS definition of 'soul' and, if yes, whether it differs from the 'human soul'.
Related:

Do Anglicans think God has a soul?
Does God have a soul according to Presbyterians?
Do Baptists say God has a soul?
What is the Methodist position on God's soul?
According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?
A question for Roman Catholicism about the soul of God?
What does Lutheranism say about God's soul?
Do Pentecostals teach that God has a soul?


Yes, God has a soul, just as we/man have a soul. The only difference is the phase God is in compared to us. God's soul/body are already inseparably connected, ours are not.
Soul:

In scripture, the term soul is used as a synonym for spirit to describe a person in four different phases of his or her eternal existence. Soul is used to describe a person in premortal life—before birth. During earth life, the soul is joined with a physical body. At death, the soul leaves the body and goes to the spirit world to await resurrection. In the Resurrection, the body and soul are inseparably connected, which is called “the redemption of the soul.”

God the Father:

Our Father in Heaven wants us to dwell with Him eternally. His work and glory is “to bring to pass the immortality and eternal life of man.” In order to make this possible, He prepared the plan of salvation.

Plan of Salvation:

Because of Christ’s Atonement, all of God’s children will be resurrected and our bodies and spirits will be reunited. Resurrection will be followed by the Final Judgment, where God will judge us according to our desires and our obedience to the commandments. If we have qualified through repentance, we will be able to live forever with our loving heavenly parents.

See also:

2 Nephi 9:13
D&C 88:15-16
Guide to Scripture: Soul

All persons are spirit children of God. He cares about each of His children and considers each one important. Because they are His children, they have the potential to become like Him.


Guide to Scripture: Spirit
D&C study guide: The Resurrection and the Judgement
D&C 130:22


For clarification, is the reason for LDS saying God has a soul because he was once a man?

@Lesley sort of by implication, there are 4 phases (1st quote), 2 of which are with a body, but only one of those is non mortal

@Lesley I feel like whenever it's "do LDS say X because God was once man" it's always the wrong way around. If anything, that comes as the result of the implication. It's not really how we should think about this, in my opinion. God is not like us; Instead, we are like God.

@kutschkem - I agree that God is not like us, because the one and the only Lord God Almighty of all creation (whom we worship) is Spirit. When the Bible says we are made in His image, that has nothing to do with our physical body. I find it impossible to accept that the God you worship was once a created man. Just can't get my head round that one!

@depperm You say "Soul is used to describe a person in premortal life—before birth." But God was never born. The God of the Bible was never created, He exists from eternity, from before the creation of life.  He is the creator of all life.  How, then, can you say that God was a soul before he was born?

When you say, in Scripture soul is a synonym for Spirit, what scripture do you mean? For instance, first Thessalonians 5:23 refers to the soul, spirit, and body of humans.  It draws a distinction rather than a synonym.

@MikeBorden The Worth of Souls clarifies the distinction: Man is a dual being—a living soul—composed of a body of spirit and a physical body. (2nd phase)

@Lesley to clarify LDS believe God had a physical body in the pre-existence (he was already at/in 4th phase). The details of God's origin/beginning are not clear/revealed in much detail.

Worth of Souls is a sermon (if that's the right word) or Scripture?  Or both?

@depperm - We must be talking about an entirely different God then because the God Christians worship has no origin or beginning according to the holy and inspired Bible.

@MikeBorden sermon is a fine word, it's a General Conference talk

@Lesley see LDS teachings/answer
